# How to remove or replace "\" in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, replace

Does anyone knows how to remove/replace from string `"/"` and  `"\"` in C#?

I have string which looks like this:

```
string myString= @"d:\Folder1\folder name2\file.ext";
```

I need either get rid of `"\"` or just get file name without all this garbage of its location.

Comment: seriously ? use the escaping character '\' so you can so myString.Replace("\\","/")

Comment: did you try it yourself in actual code? C# throw exception before you even attemp to rebuild your project. I am in VS 2010. Which one you using?

Comment: string temp = @"c:\".Replace("\\", "/"); perfectly compiles

Comment: not on my version. as soon as I have string str_myString= (str_filenm.Replace("\\", ".")).Replace(":", ".");  bunch of error pop with missing ) and  ; and could not read beyond line# and so on.

Comment: copy/paste my code, and you'll see it's working (there is no difference between .net/visual studio version at this level), there is something in yours like the useless ()

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) class

```
Path.GetFileName(str_myString);
Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(str_myString);
```

Whenever you need to do something modifying a path, the Path class is a go-to solution.  It's platform-specific, and at least on windows, it supports both `/` and `\` (via `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` and `Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar`).

Answer (score 0):

Hope bellow syntax will be help full for you

```
string inputString = @"hello world]\ ";

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            string[] parts = inputString.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\n', '\t', '\r', '\f', '\v','\\' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            int size = parts.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                sb.AppendFormat("{0} ", parts[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks for effort but that is not what I need. See answer above.